# How to subtract 1 minute from hour

Tags: sql

I have a query contains from time and to time parameters.
I need to subtract 1 minute from totime parameter.
I used totime-1.
It is working in database level and it is not working in my crystal reports.I mean it is subtracting 1 hour in report level.
Can any one please tell me other formula for subtracting a minute.

Thanks,
vissu

Comment: this is likely to depend on which database vendor you are using...  can you specify?

Comment: Can you post the part of your code? Which SQL engine are you using? You might have better luck getting the time in seconds. See: http://shafiqissani.wordpress.com/2010/09/30/how-to-get-the-current-epoch-time-unix-timestamp/ for different ways with different vendors.

Comment: In Standard SQL, you'd use `timeval - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE`.  There are only a few DBMS that support that notation, and there are many different alternative ways to do it, depending on which DBMS you use.  One would use `timeval - INTERVAL(1) MINUTE TO MINUTE` or `timeval - 1 UNITS MINUTE`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Serve/T-sql

```
DATEADD(MI, -1, totime)
```

Answer (score 0):

In some databases (SQL Server and Oracle for instance), you can do the following:

```
select totime - 1.0/(24*60)
```

Time differences are measured in days, so 1.0/(24*60) is one minute represented as a fraction of a day.

MySQL accepts the syntax, but the timestamp is measured in seconds not days, so you would use:

```
select totime - 60
```

Comment: Can you justify 'most'?  I can believe that is valid for some DBMS, but 'most' seems likely to be an overstatement.

Comment: Interesting; that's certainly a significant set of DBMS that you list.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler . . . Thank you for keeping me honest.  I thought Postgres supported the syntax, but there it is a string you can add, not an integer.  In any case, if Postgres supports something, I would say "most databases" because it provides the code base for so many database engines.  But, I was wrong, so I revised the answer.